# Invoking original unmolested window.open from bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, dom, opera, bookmarklet

I have general purpose bookmarklet, which begins with:

```
javascript:with (window.open("")) {/* lots of irrelevant characters */
```

It works as should (opens new window and writes a report about page elements, specifically), however fails on certain pages, when authors decide what `open` is a good name for function:

```
/* somewhere in global scope */
function open() { /* something */ }
```

... effectively replacing `window.open` and breaking bookmarklet operation. By the nature of bookmarklet i cannot do anything to prevent such misbehaviour.

Is there any way to call original native `window.open` to recover in this cases?
Please note, my primary browser is Opera, i really want to make it work in there.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.constructor.prototype.open
```

<strike>Nope, sorry.  You can do some hackery to get a new one though :)</strike>

var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
   
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
   
ifr.contentWindow.open(...)

Comment: Cool, thanks. Thinking out of the box is great, i was digging into prototypes while could just easily obtain a fresh copy :-)

Comment: didn't think of that!  `window.constructor.prototype.open`

Comment: FYI: Firefox allows to `delete window.open` revealing a native metdod.

Comment: hehe, also nice.  Of course you break the page you're on if you do that.

Comment: wait, wait, it is undefined in Opera, tried that before, their window implementation seems to be special